# i want to execute certain code at midnight every day but it does not excute it execute only when web application is open

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, cron

When i run the code once it execute after that the code does not execute on it on. it is to be executed once a day but it execute when i start my website

i have used cronjob in my code and if u are comfortable with thread its fine

my code is as follow..

in global.asax i have this code

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        // get a scheduler
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
            .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
            .Build();

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
          .StartNow()
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24)
              .RepeatForever())
          .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        // CreatingNewThreadTimer();
    }
```

and hellojob is my class that is to be executed

Comment: Placing some code you need to execute by some schedule into web application is not a good idea. Consider placing your code into separate executable file and run it when you need, by windows task scheduler.

Comment: You meant Quartz.Net right? Not cron.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev It's not a good idea to roll your own solution, but there are tried and tested libraries that remove much of the headaches. Scott Hanselman (Microsoft employee) discusses many of them [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Comment: @mason I wouldn't call something that should start at a certain time independent of a certain system a background task of that system. It is something different.

Comment: @Ralf Yes, it most definitely is a background task, because the goal is not to execute it within the context of an HTTP request/response cycle but upon a schedule. Hence, it's a background task.

Comment: Before going into an unhelpful meta discussion lets simply agree that we have a dissent.

Comment: but didntget my solution @Ralf

Comment: Now the  problem is that my code is running but the issue is that it run till only the website is open in browser after that  it does not run